# How to minimize all opened applications and show home screen?

Tags: android, android-intent

I searched but did not get solution for this. I want to show home screen like pressing home key in android devices by click on button.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can show the homescreen like this:

```
Intent startMain = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
startMain.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
startMain.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(startMain);
```

Comment: In that case, please accept the answer so others can find it :)